# What's the difference between "New Document" and "Upload Document"?

Tags: document-library, document, file

I have a library. In the `Files` tab in the ribbon bar, there are these two buttons, "New Document" and "Upload Document".

Both have exactly the same behavior: opening a modal dialog where I can upload a file (optionally specifying where I want it uploaded). Then a modal form, one where I can choose the new document's content type, and based on that fill out the rest of the metadata.

I am writing a manual to our users on how to work with files and I wouldn't like to say "just click either button, they both do the same thing". What is the difference between those two buttons? Do they behave differently in a normal situation, and only do the very same thing if you configure something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The New Document button should open the template specified on the document library for the user. Then they can save the document back into the library. Upload Document is just that, uploads a doc.

If you're seeing Upload for the New, I think this is because you either don't have a template specified for your content type, or you're on a browser that doesn't full support Office integration.

HTH

Comment: Right to the spot. I don't have a template. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The new document will open the application (word or excel) for you to create a new document. The upload document will direct you to browse for a file (that is already created and saved) so you can upload it.