# Document library - "New" vs. "Upload"

Tags: document-library, file-upload, template

I am running into an issue where clicking the "new" option in the document library header opens the same dialog as clicking "upload".

A similar question was asked here, [What's the difference between "New Document" and "Upload Document"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77655/whats-the-difference-between-new-document-and-upload-document), but the solution is not working for me. The document library is setup to only handle Word Documents and I have assigned a template using ListSettings->ConentTypes(Document)->AdvancedSettings->Enter the Url of an existing document template. I am using a .dotx that is essentially a blank word document. I am experiencing the same issue on chrome and internet explorer

According to this, [What's the difference between "New Document" and "Upload Document"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77655/whats-the-difference-between-new-document-and-upload-document) , answer the default toolbar has the new button referring to "upload.aspx", but that doesn't make much since to be because the upload button also points to Upload.aspx. You can change it to "show toolbar", but I don't think it fits the theme as well + wouldn't I need to do that with every library?

This is Sharepoint 2016. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the template in the document library instead of setting it in the content type? You should go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Document Template - Template URL

Comment: Yes. The template listed there is greyed out, but it is the same template as referenced above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your SharePoint 2016 farm to an Office Online Server farm. Run the following PowerShell command from a SharePoint Management Shell:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName oos.domain.net
```

where *oos.domain.net* is the DNS name of the Office Online Server farm on your network. Obviously, you need to install OOS first and on a dedicated server. It cannot co-exist with SharePoint. See this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34289.install-configure-office-online-server.aspx) for details how-to install OOS.

Once SharePoint is connected to OOS the New button will look like this:

[image]

On a side note, OOS is a great value add to SharePoint giving users the ability to open and edit Office documents in the browser. On top of that they also get document previews in document libraries and search results. However, beware of OOS licensing policies. The ability to edit documents in the browser requires a license.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2016, in case anyone comes across this...  If you create your library based on the "Form Library" template, instead of "Document Library", the "new" button will create a new doc based on your template.